Story about aliens traveling on a comet
I am looking for a book or story that I read in a book about 30 years ago about the investigation of some mysterious deaths in which the victims have dry brains.
In the end it turns out that the culprits are aliens who are approaching Earth in a comet that passes every few years (about 1000). The aliens kill in this way because they believe that humans have already developed technology to read information from the brains of the dead since the last time the comet passed near Earth.
Initially I thought that it was a Asimov story, but I didn't find anything like that.

Can you explain what "dry brains" means? For example does it mean an autopsy showed the brains were dried out and shrivelled up?

Thanks for your question @JohnRennie. I can remember, but, I think was shrivelled up.
